# No puedo hacer zoom desde dispositivos móviles en una página

Tags: html, css3

Pues como digo en el título, estoy cambiando una web y ella se ve bien en dispositivos móviles pero no puedo hacer zoom en ella,ni ampliar ni reducir.
Y me han pedido que se pueda hacer zoom en ella.
He utilizado la etiqueta viewport:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=0.25,maximum-scale=2.5, user-scalable=yes">
```

La página se ve bien en responsive, pero quiero poder hacer zoom. Las capas están con ancho en porcentajes.

Comment: quieres hacer zoom luego de un evento?

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Me gustaría hacer zoom sin eventos, un zoom móvil normal.

Comment: En Stackoverflow no existe agradecimientos, sino solamente preguntas adecuadas y respuestas puntuales

Comment: He conseguido hacer zoom (ampliar) cambiando solo los ajustes del móvil pero no puedo disminuir. Por lo que puede que el viewport no este mal. He quitado el width=device-width

Answer (score 1):

La etiqueta base de la que debes partir debe ser esta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Y el zoom debe funcionar, lo tengo en varios proyectos y en todos funciona

> PD: por defecto el scalable ya está en `yes`

Answer (score 0):

estas poniendo

```
minimum-scale=0.25
```

el cual no te deja hacer min a tu pagina, prueba cambiando el valor